# How to figure out why my webpage from crashing Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, browser, profiling

I am building a page that displays a list of images when you click a button and binds some JavaScript functions to allow you to perform some actions on those images. The html exists on page load, but is hidden until the button is clicked. For some users of the application, Google Chrome consistently crashes when they click to display this list.

I have a hunch that Chrome is only crashing for users that have the most images. I'm guessing that Chrome is crashing when it tries to load so many images at the same time. I believe this is a browser bug (Chrome should be smart enough not to request so many images that it crashes), but until Chrome fixes this behavior, I'm going to have to adapt my code. It's possible that adding some sort of pagination will fix this problem, however, the solution isn't really my question. The problem is that I don't have any data to back up my assumption.

I'd like to know how to debug/profile this scenario so I can see if that is the reason it is crashing.

Comment: @csanonymus Sorry, I can't give you a link. That's also outside the scope of this question. I just want to know general advice for debugging these sorts of scenarios.